# How to solve Mongodb Duplicate Key Error on deletedAt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using mongoose-delete https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-delete 
I am gettings this error

> E11000 duplicate key error index: hose_api.takeoffs.$horse_1_competition_1_event_1_deletedAt_1 dup key: { : ObjectId('5dd5dcb0f1dbcd08d0dda8ca'), : ObjectId('5f89f86444a69c11583086dd'), : ObjectId('5f89ed7504266450e81ea5ef'), : new Date(1602881879322) }"}

Every time i try to soft delete the document.
 
This is the index that i am using:

> { "horse": 1, "competition": 1, "event": 1, "deletedAt": 1 }

document example:

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f8a086a414a1a5d941557e0"
        },
        "entry": 0,
        "hasPass": false,
        "pass": 3,
        "order": 999999,
        "deleted": true,
        "competitor": {
            "$oid": "5e5f1a9e020c37154079fc15"
        },
        "competition": {
            "$oid": "5f89f86444a69c11583086dd"
        },
        "horse": {
            "$oid": "5dd5dcb0f1dbcd08d0dda8ca"
        },
        "payment": "NONE",
        "event": {
            "$oid": "5f89ed7504266450e81ea5ef"
        },
        "owner": {
            "$oid": "5e056556b3b6192584c1f7a2"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2020-10-16T20:57:59.322Z"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2020-10-16T20:54:02.268Z"
        },
        "__v": 0,
        "deletedAt": {
            "$date": "2020-10-16T20:57:59.322Z"
        },
        "deletedBy": null
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code which performs deletion?

Comment: it's this one https://github.com/dsanel/mongoose-delete

Comment: tksLast = await TakeOff.delete({
              competitor: takeoff.competitor,
              horse: takeoff.horse,
              competition: comp._id,
            });